# Android application share option on settings on Motorola devices

Tags: android, settings, share

Seems like some Android devices have Share option. Which is available when user go to settings App and click on any app. Upon click it gives user option to share Android market link and a short message via email or text message. So far i am seeing this only on Motorola devices. I am trying to change the message without any luck.

I already looked into Settings and ApplicationInfo but nothing there was helpful. Any suggestion? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "Share" button is not part of standard Android. I doubt that you have any control over the behavior of that button. You might consider asking on the MOTODEV support boards, if you believe that this is a Motorola feature.